# For a given item X and shopping records array, write code to find out what else (item Y) was bought mostly by the customers who bought item X

Tags: algorithm

We have an array representing customer’s shopping records.
For example, it’s an array like this:

```
custA, item1,
custB, item1,
custA, item2,
custB, item3,
custC, item1,
custC, item3,
custD, item2,
```

This array indicates that customer A bought item 1, customer B bought item 1, customer A bought item 2, customer B bought item 3, etc..
For a given item X and shopping records array, write code to find out what else (item Y) was bought mostly by the customers who bought item X.
For example, in above example, if X is item 1 then Y should be item 3.

Answer (score 0):

well one approach could be iterate over 2D array and find list(or map for efficiently lookup) of people who bought item1.
then create a map of itemName and purchasedCount by iterating over array again in this cycle put entries in map for people who are present on list of item1 buyers.
now iterate over the map again and find the desired item.
for N*2 array this approach require 3N iteration and require space upto 3N(N for buyers list, and N*2 for item count map, plus map consumes additional space)